# According to the Catholic Church, can a tattoo be considered a sacramental?

Tags: catholicism, sacramentals, tattoos

**According to the Catholic Church, can a tattoo be considered a sacramental?**

I have a friend who is thinking about getting a tattoo on each shoulder, containing the image of the [Medal of St. Benedict](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Benedict_Medal). There are several different blessings for this medal now. Any priest may bless the Medal of St. Benedict and some blessings have the word image in lieu of the word medal.

If a priest were to bless this image would it be considered a sacrament, according to the Catholic Church.

Although I am bring up the case of the Medal of St. Benedict, any other image in use in this question could hold also.

In the case of lack of official Catholic 
Church teachings on this subject could a priest simply bless such holy images? Is there any Church prohibitions against this?

Are priests allowed to bless tattoos? After all there are also blessings for people in the Rituale Romanum!

Here follows the image of the  Medal of St. Benedict that my friend is considering.

[image: St.Benedict Medal]

[St. Benedict Medal](https://christthekingpriory.com/medals/medal-12)

Comment: "_there are also blessings for people in the Rituale Romanum!_" What about for body parts?

Comment: Also, [_sacramentum_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=sacramentum#lexicon) in Classical Latin meant a "military oath of allegiance". I heard the Roman soldiers tattooed/branded themselves, and that was also called a "_sacramentum_".

Comment: Leviticus 19:28  (NRSVCE) says: 

"You shall not make any gashes in your flesh for the dead or tattoo any marks upon you: I am the Lord."

If the priest thinks that the instructions of Leviticus are outdated, he can bless the tattoo, but one wonders whether that makes for a sacramental!

Comment: By raising the right hand and making the sign of the cross I'm not sure how the priest is going to bless the tattoo without blessing the person by mistake.

Comment: @LuisTavares When one holds a medal to be blessed and a priest employs a certain phrase of blessing, it is obvious that the medal is blessed, even if it is held in one’s hand.

Comment: @Ken Graham Yes, Objects can also be blessed. In this case I'm not even sure that a tattoo can be considered a `body part`. More like an object, maybe!

Comment: Is not an image an object or something like a painting on the skin. It is not a body part per say in any definition of the word.

Comment: This question will be better answered by a Catholic priest, preferably, a tattooed one, https://denvercatholic.org/forgive-father-tattoo-hey/

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan since the context of this question is specifically Catholicism, you might consider that taking a single quote out of Scripture rarely constitutes a definitive doctrinal declaration in Catholicism

Comment: `Can tattoos be sacramentals?`. The short answer to this question seems to be `No`, according to theologians and priests asked recently by CNA, https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/can-tattoos-be-sacramentals-67281

Comment: @LuisTavares please don't answer in the comments under questions, that would make for a very good supported answer!

Comment: @Peter Turner Sorry! Newbie here!

Comment: @luis that's OK - we always like to see new faces!  But it's best when they're answering questions.  That's the fastest way you can get reputation on the site to be able to do more stuff (comment on other posts, chat, see review queues, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the only time the word ***medals*** is mentioned in the [ARTICLE 1 - SACRAMENTALS](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c4a1.htm) of the CCC is under the Popular Piety section,

(*italic* is mine)

> **Popular piety**
>
> **1674** *Besides* sacramental liturgy and *sacramentals*, catechesis must
>   take into account the forms of piety and popular devotions among the
>   faithful. The religious sense of the Christian people has always found
>   expression in various forms of piety surrounding the Church's
>   sacramental life, such as the veneration of relics, visits to
>   sanctuaries, pilgrimages, processions, the stations of the cross,
>   religious dances, the rosary, *medals, etc*.

This paragraph is giving the impression that not even medals can be considered sacramentals!

There is also an ***etc*** in the end of the paragraph sufficiently ambiguous.

Better consult the [Compendium of the CCC](http://www.vatican.va/archive/compendium_ccc/documents/archive_2005_compendium-ccc_en.html)

(*italic* is mine)

> **351. What are the sacramentals?**
>
> 1667-1672 
>   1677-1678
>
> These are sacred signs instituted by the Church to sanctify different
>   circumstances of life. They include a prayer accompanied by the sign
>   of the cross and other signs. Among the sacramentals which occupy an
>   important place are: blessings, which are the praise of God and a
>   prayer to obtain his gifts, the consecration of persons and the
>   *dedication of things* for the worship of God.

Can a tattoo be considered a *thing*? Don't know.

Better ask a "tattooed millennial priest":

[Can tattoos be sacramentals?](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/can-tattoos-be-sacramentals-67281) [Article from the CNA]

> “Sacramentals, used well, keep us close to the grace of Christ given
>   to us in the seven sacraments, and receive their graces by the
>   authority that Christ gives his bride, the Church, when she asks for
>   his help. When the Church asks Christ for graces, He never refuses his
>   bride,”

and

> “This means that sacramentals only work when they are done according
>   to the rules of the Church. If we want to ask Christ for these graces,
>   we need to make sure we do so authentically as the Church, obediently
>   accepting the rules she sets down. It's clear in Canon Law that the
>   Apostolic See alone has the authority to establish sacramentals and
>   define the criteria for their use [c. 1167],”

and

> "However, he added, it is possible that tattoos could be
>   “sacramentals” in a broader sense of the word."

which means in a strict sense they are not.

He keeps talking,

> “A permanent image, engraved on the skin, could certainly serve as a
>   constant, physical reminder of our new life in Christ. The image of a
>   rosary, a cross, or other sacramental on our skin could lead us
>   frequently to pray, to desire the seven sacraments more, and to think
>   and act in communion with the Church,” he said.

and finally,

> “So, while a tattoo could not fulfill the requirements to be a proper
>   sacramental in itself, if used in discernment and good faith it could
>   certainly provide similar benefits and be helpful in the pursuit of
>   holiness.”

And here we have the confirmation that tattoos can not be considered sacramentals.

I can't confirm a tattoo can be blessed without being considered a sacramental.

Answer (score 1):

[Sacramentals](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36179) are defined in [1917 canons 1144](https://archive.org/details/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary/page/n1878)-5 (cf. [1983 canons 1166](http://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann1166-1190_en.html#TITLE_I)-7):

> 1144. The Sacramentals are objects or actions resembling the Sacraments which the Church makes use of by way of intercession to obtain especially spiritual effects.
>       <sub>[[Latin](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/LAT0813/_P3Q.HTM):] Sacramentalia sunt res aut actiones quibus Ecclesia, in aliquam Sacramentorum imitationem, uti solet ad obtinendos ex sua impetratione effectus praesertim spirituales.</sub>
> 1145. The Apostolic See alone can institute Sacramentals, authentically interpret those in use, or abolish or change some of them.
>       <sub>[[Latin](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/LAT0813/_P3Q.HTM):] Nova Sacramentalia constituere aut recepta authentice interpretari, ex eisdem aliqua abolere aut mutare, sola potest Sedes Apostolica.</sub>

So, no, tattoos cannot be considered sacramentals because the Apostolic See has not considered them as such.

---

Also, as attested in [ch. 5 of his autobiography](https://ccel.org/ccel/suso/susolife/susolife.iii.v.html), Bl. Henry Suso, O.P., inscribed the Name of Jesus into his breast with a stylus, but there is no indication that he or anyone else considered it a sacramental. It seems for him  to have had the effects of a sacramental, conferring grace not *[ex opere operato](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33474)* ("from the work performed," as in the sacraments) but *[ex opere operantis](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33472)* (from his pious dispositions, as in the sacramentals).

Comment: I've got a feeling this is a tad more pedantic an answer than is necessary. You may be right, but you may also still be wrong.  Reading the Catechism 1668-1676 would not necessarily lead me to this answer.

Comment: @PeterTurner "_you may also still be wrong_" Possibly. Proving the non-existence of something (that the Church hasn't even considered a tattoo a sacramental) is more difficult than proving its existence.

Comment: I was thinking that by a less rigid definition of sacramental, at least, a person's body might be considered sacramental, then you'd only have to consider whether or not the tattoo was a part of someone's body or not

Answer (score 1):

I have a tattoo of Mary, I summoned a priest to be there during the whole process, he blessed the machine for use, the artist, me and the ink, upon completion the art got blessed as well with holy water. While he didn't confirm this would be considered as a sacrament he approved the process itself. I still wear my cross and medals at all times. For me it was a tribute no one ever can take away from me and that was its meaning.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Personal experiences or opinions are not relative.  The O.P. wants the official Catholic Church view.